# show that $2n\choose n$ is divisible by 2

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, induction

I tried using induction, but in the inductive step, I get:

If $2n\choose n$ is divisible then I want to see that $2n +2\choose n +1$

$${2n +2\choose n +1} = (2n + 2)!/(n+1)!(n +1)! = {2n\choose n} (2n+1)(2n+2)/(n+1)^2$$

$$= {2n\choose n} 2(2n+1)/(n+1)$$

Then ${2n\choose n}$ is divisible by $2$ by hypothesis, but $2(2n+1)/(n+1)$ is not even an integer.

What can I do?

Comment: Hint: Pascal's triangle rule gives
$${2n \choose n}={2n-1\choose n}+{2n-1\choose n-1}.$$ BTW, this is a duplicate. Will look for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing it directly rather than by induction - consider how many times 2 appears in the expansion of the numerator and denominator into prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

Direct way: from [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec3.pdf), corollary 14 in page 4:

> Corollary 14. The power of prime $p$ dividing $n \choose k$ is the number of carries when you add $k$ to $n − k$ in base $p$ (and also the number of carries when you subtract $k$ from $n$ in
>   base $p$)

So it is enough to proove that when you adding $n$ to itself in base 2 you have at least one carry, which is obvious follow from that $n$ have at least one 1 digit in binary.